# C++11 Raw String Literals Macro Visual Studio

Tags: c++11, macros, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings, string-literals

Is it still an issue in VS2013 update 4
I have this macro defined:

```
#define STR LR"(c:\program files)"
```

However when compiling below

```
cout<< STR
```

I get a compilation warning (warning C4129: 'p'), seems like the compiler disregards macro expansion of the Raw literal directive.
Is it still a compiler bug? When Microsoft shall fix it?

Comment: Probably not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: Nothing indicates that works in macros: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx

Comment: Interesting, both raw and wide raw literals work outside of macros, raw literals work in macros, but wide raw literals don't. Looks like a bug. Maybe try to submit a bug at connect.microsoft.com: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: Just checked VS2015 Preview - the issue is reproducible. Also, after preprocessing there is `cout << L"(c:\program files)"`, so looks like the bug is in preprocessor.

Comment: A somewhat related [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/937959)

Comment: Thanks Paul, opened bug, id 1065705

Comment: A related problem:  `assert(Parse(R"(The path is "C:\Program Files\test.exe")"));`. The assert macro uses `#` to make a string version of the expression by putting quotes around it.  This results in the guts being treated as escaped characters rather than raw text.  Thus you get the same warning about `\P` and the `\t` is transformed into a tab.  As far as I can tell, this is not a bug but rather a bad interaction between raw string literals and assert-like macros.